# Excel cells have hyperlink format

Tags: excel

So i just came across this. I am pretty new to excel, but i tried almsot everything i could find on google, and nothing worked. Basically, my columns are sharing one hyperlink, and i don't know how to get rid of it. Link to my file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1UgN77eGAIESEFqLVZNbDRzWHc/edit?usp=sharing)

I tried deleting formatting of cells, or delete any leftover hyperlinks, but excel isn't even showing any, but when i open it in drive, there is still hyperlink in columns 4-8.

Any ideas what causes it, and what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

When I open your file, the columns are delineated as you desire.
Using excel, try saving the file in a different format such as *.csv and then opening it.